# Broken png image using Laravel Asset Pipeline despite 200 OK status

Tags: php, image, http, laravel-4

I'm using [Codesleeve/asset pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) on my Laravel project to serve css, js and image files. It on the whole works fine but there is an issue with displaying css-loaded images. The image does not display and shows the browser's "broken image" symbol when loading it directly (http://art.ipscap.com/assets/select2.png for example): e.g. [image: broken image]

Upon inspecting the page it shows the image is loaded successfully with 200 OK status (or cached) but there seems to be an error displaying it. Seeing as the image in question displays fine on my local machine and the problem is only in production is there a way to diagnose this issue?

**Edit:** Still haven' t managed to find a solution for this. For reference the live broken image url is https://art.ipscap.com/assets/select2.png. The image itself is in `app/assets/images/select2.png` and the readme in the same directory states:

> If you place an image here called `foobar.png` then you can access that image by going to `http://<hostname>/assets/foobar.png`

I find it strange as the image does not fail to load but is being broken by asset pipeline. The same does not seem to occur to other images in the app such as the header jpeg image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use different server software on your local and production server? I see the production uses nginx. In that case, you might have to add something to your config as stated here:

https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#can-i-use-nginx

Comment: Indeed I am using Nginx on my production server but I have set up the config correctly and hence the image does load (200) but appears to be broken or corrupted.